# Does sitemap.xml have to be in the root directory?

Tags: seo, sitemap

This may be a simple and absurd question, but is it completely necessary for sitemap.xml file to be in the root directory of the wordpress install directory of the site, or is it ok to create a subdirectory and place it there? i.e. /sitemap/sitemap.xml

I've created a dynamically generated site map xml file, but would like to auto-generate it on the fly when changes are made, and need to be able to write to this file. I would like to keep the main wordpress folder permissions as they are and only have this subdirectory writable.

Would love to hear any thoughts on the matter! Or alternate solutions... Merci!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Yes and No](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location). From the sitemap.org *official* site:-

> The location of a Sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be
>   included in that Sitemap. A Sitemap file located at
>   `http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml` can include any URLs starting
>   with `http://example.com/catalog/` but can not include URLs starting
>   with `http://example.com/images/`.

So **yes**, you can locate it outside the root, but **doing so does limit the url set you can include** if you correctly observe the protocol.

You can inform Google and Bing of your sitemap's location via their webmaster tools interface, but I can't say if they actually care about the URL set when sitemap.xml is not located in the root. IMHO I would observe the protocol.

Full details http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location

Since you're using wordpress, there are many plugins which can do the job for you, I recommend [Google (XML) Sitemaps Generator for WordPress](http://www.arnebrachhold.de/projects/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-generator/) (which supports custom post types, be careful when selecting alternative plugins as many others don't support this feature).

Comment: @Starfs what's the issue you're having, I run about 30 Wordpress sites and have never had an issue with root security settings and the sitemap...

Comment: -as I understand it, in order for a file to be writable, its needs to be in a writable directory... Is this a correct assumption, and if so, wouldn't that pose potential risks?

Comment: @Starfs your site root should be chmod 755 - this would cause no problems for a sitemap.

Comment: FYI both Google and Bing allow any URLs in a sitemap, not just those below the current folder. Also, I'm sure this is a dupe question.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I'm pretty sure both do, but I can't find any documentation from either that supports that notion, so I stuck with the spec in the answer.

Comment: @Disgruntled Goat let us know if you find any document to support this. Also, I searched for this question but couldn't find it easily, thus it is here now

Comment: Here is my documentation: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/23933/233 (i.e. personal experience)

Comment: Interesting. I think I will still stick with the site map specs, but it is good to know this could work, just in case

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat yes, your answer matches my experience too, which is why I equivocated in the answer. I don't think that it matters, but beyond personal experience, I can't prove that's the case and Google does have a strong history of changing it's mind on these things.

Comment: For Google: If you submit the Sitemap-URL via robots.txt, you can place it anywhere (even on other sites). If you submit via Google Webmaster Tools, the Sitemap can be anywhere within any verified site (so in subdirectories of a verified site, or on other domains). Source: [Help Center](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75712) & [blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2007/10/dealing-with-sitemap-cross-submissions.html) [posts](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2008/02/cross-submissions-via-robotstxt-on.html)

Comment: @JohnMueller "Cross-site submissions will work only if all sites have been verified in Webmaster Tools." and we do not know how other search engines have implemented the protocol.